# Scale bold capital letters

Tags: math-mode, fonts, bold, calligraphy

I have my custom fonts. They are fine in terms of size. However the bold fonts for capital letters are too big and I do not know how to normalize their size.

[image: scale bold capital letters]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{calligra}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcalligra}{T1}{calligra}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{calligra}{m}{n}{<->s*[2.2]callig15}{}
\newcommand{\customfont}[1]{\mathcalligra{#1}\,}
\newcommand{\boldcustomfont}[1]{\pmb{\mathcalligra{#1}}\,}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} \\
&{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\
&\customfont{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} \\
&\customfont{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\
&\boldcustomfont{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} \\
&\boldcustomfont{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The (faked) bold letters are as high as the medium ones. I find that font not suitable for math: its property of having a much smaller x-height than height of ascenders is what makes it difficult to combine the font with others.

Comment: @Mico, many thanks. But the scale affects both upper and lower case. How can I affect them separately?

Comment: If you really want to scale the letters indepently in one font you need an intermediary virtual font that combines the font in two sizes.

Comment: @Mico, Can I define two different commands one for uppercases and the other for lowercases?

Comment: @Mico, That's great. But how to do that?

Comment: @Mico, `mtpro2` is not for free. Even for personal use, I prefer to avoid. My latex knowledge is low but I feel it is possible to create two commands, one scale 1 and the other scales 2.2 without caring what is inside curly brackets. The responsibility is shifted to user to apply them properly. Does this idea work?

Comment: @Mico, No I understood what you mean and did not misinterpret. I tried  `\newcommand{\customfontbig}[1]{{\relsize{2.2}\mathcalligra{#1}\,}}` which did not work. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: @Mico, I did not disregard your comments but my knowledge in latex is low and I do not know how to implement them. Just that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, many thanks. Would you please advise how to implement it?